# Why my variable is list of list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

In my LWC js file, I have one list variable, but when I assign values to it, it's becoming list of list.

This is the current structure which I'm getting:

```
**[[{"name":"Report - All-2020-03-18-06-50-31.xlsx","documentId":"06956000000leZPAAY"}],[{"name":"Salesforce Hero.png","documentId":"06956000000leZUAAY"}]]**
```

JS File:

```
export default class CreateScreen extends LightningElement {
    @track uploadedFiles =[];
    handleUploadFinished(event) {
            this.uploadedFiles = [...this.uploadedFiles, event.detail.files];
            console.log("No. of files uploaded : " + this.uploadedFiles);
            console.log("No. of files uploaded : " + JSON.stringify(this.uploadedFiles));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `event.detail.files` is always a list. Try this instead:

```
this.uploadedFiles = [...this.uploadedFiles, ...event.detail.files];
```

Answer (score 2):

> The files attribute is the list of files that are uploaded.

So you need to concatenate two lists.

```
this.uploadedFiles = this.uploadedFiles.concat(event.detail.files);
```